# 'System.InvalidCastException: Can't write CLR type System.String with handler type NumericHandler' Very stuck on data type issue in postgresql with C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am re-writing some old VB code to C# and converting everything to postgresql from informix and sql server.  I am quite stuck on an issue that I believe is a data type issue due to postgresql being stricter with data types.  Before I tried casting `AS NUMERIC`.  I also tried not using type casting in the `pstrng` sql string as well.

I tried changing `NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType`'s to every different data type that would make sense.  I feel like I tried everything.  Also to be transparent, I am not that well-versed in postgresql so it's possible it's some obvious easy syntax thing.

Below is the declaration of variables:

```cs
string aString;
int id = 0;
string cmpyid = "";
string tgnn = "";
string inm = "";
string Whs = "";
string ft = "0";
string gh_lt = "0";
string gll = "0";
string ghsd = "1998/01/01";
string gag = "0";
string gsd = "0";
var dList = new List<string>();
string Gge = "";
double Gcv = 0.0d;
double Pgcv = 0.0d;
string ft = "";
int fconv = 0;
double pnum = 0.0d;
decimal anm = 0.0m;
decimal dv = 0.0m;
decimal sdn = 0.0m;
decimal tdvv = 0.0m;
decimal eage = 0.0m;
decimal ie = 0.0m;
decimal tm = 0.0m;
```

Below is the code where something is going wrong:

```cs
string pstrng= "";
pstrng= @"UPDATE gamma_header 
          SET 
              CAST('ft=@ftt' AS DECIMAL), CAST(gh_lt=@ghl AS DECIMAL),
              CAST(gag = @gav AS DECIMAL), CAST(gsd = @gst AS DECIMAL)
          WHERE gmpid = 'IOP' and tg = @gmtg and inm = @ginm";

var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = (System.Data.CommandType)Convert.ToInt16(CommandType.Text);
cmd.CommandText = pstrng;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@gma_tg", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = tgnn;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ginm ", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = inm;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ftt", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = ft;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ghl", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = gh_lt;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@glll", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = gll;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gsd", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = ghsd;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gav", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = gag;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@gst", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = gsd;
using (var con = new NpgsqlConnection(GlobalVariables.consql)) // (strConnString)
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

The error I get is `System.InvalidCastException: Can't write CLR type System.String with handler type NumericHandler`  I've tried type casting, changing the initial data types of declared variables, and changing the Npgsql data types.  None of it is working.  Please help.

Comment: What is the significance of `CAST('ft=@ftt' AS DECIMAL)`?  I don't think that string (`'ft=@ftt'`) could be cast to a numeric type

Comment: A couple of other comments: The bulk of your code was indented 52 spaces; consider that many folks access this site on a phone.  Why do you initialize `pstrng` to an empty string and then immediately assign it another value.  You don't have to initialize things when you declare them (and, if you leave things uninitialized, in some cases the compiler can help you prevent bugs)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `NpgsqlCommand` is disposable (it implements IComponent, and that interface declares itself to be disposable).  You probably want another `using`: `using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand());`

Comment: @Flydog57 I honestly don't know, I just ran my VB code through a converter.  I'm confused on why it was originally written that way too...  I think that's the issue, but I don't know how to solve it. ("It" being how it's declared as a string, I don't know wtf to do with it now)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this

```
CAST('ft=@ftt' AS DECIMAL)
```

be something like

```
ft = CAST(@ftt AS DECIMAL)
```

?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure.  I'll try that out and report back, thanks.

Comment: And the parameter types should match the .NET variable types.

Comment: So, for instance, say `ft = CAST(@ftt AS DECIMAL)` would actually be `AS TEXT` instead since the C# variable is a string?  I'm confusing myself here.

Comment: Yes.  Then the SQL CAST function will change the incoming string to a DECIMAL before assigning the value to the column `ft`.  If your parameter type is Numeric, then convert the value to a numeric type in .NET before assigning it to the parameter's .Value property.

Comment: I gotta be honest, I never figured this out.  I went on to other issues and had a 3-day weekend.  I feel like I'm doing this right but apparently I'm not as I'm still getting the error.

I changed the variable declarations of `ft, gh_lt, gll, gag, gsd` from `string` to `decimal` this morning to see if that would help. But it broke other parts of the code.

I feel like I tried everything but nothing is working.  It's probably something really simple but I think this issue is a brick wall for me for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hardly a Npgsql expert, but your error looks like the .NET bits can't convert a string using a numeric converter.

Looking at your `Parameters`, it looks like you're telling the engine `@ftt` s should be `NpgsqlDbType.Numeric`, and you pass in a string (`ft`). Ditto for `gh_lt`, `gll`, etc. Similarly, the date `gsd` should likely be a native .NET DateTime, not a string.

Beyond that, your `SET` syntax seems off...

So, how about letting the adapter deal with data types (and for the love of everything that's holy, please rename those variables to something that makes sense when you get the chance... :-) )

```
string tgnn = "";
string inm = "";
var ft = 0;
var gh_lt = 0;
var gll = 0;
var ghsd = DateTime.Parse("1998/01/01");
var gag = 0;
var gsd = 0;
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"UPDATE gamma_header
SET
ft = @ftt,
gh_lt = @ghl,
gag = @gav,
gsd = @gst
WHERE
gmpid = 'IOP'
and tg = @gmtg
and inm = @ginm");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gma_tg", tgnn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ginm", inm);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ftt", ft);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ghl", gh_lt);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("glll", gll);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gav", gag);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gst", gsd);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gsd", ghsd);
```