# In PostgreSQL can you do Npgsql parameters out of the WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

So, I've been stuck for a while as my Npgsql Parameters won't work. ([Here's my previous post which I never resolved for context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73476267/system-invalidcastexception-cant-write-clr-type-system-string-with-handler-ty))

I've suspected it has to do with the slight differences of PostgreSQL from older Informix and SQL server code. (I'm re-writing old VB code to C# and changing the older Informix and SQL Server code to PostgreSQL)

Example of my SQL string: `sqlString = @"UPDATE gh SET tt_ft=@ft, ghllt=@ghlt, glls=@gll WHERE id = 'ASDF' and tgn = @gtgn and ip = @gip";`

Example of my Npgsql parameter in C#: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@mls", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = mlss;`

But according to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482569/statement-for-npgsql-using-parameter) apparently I may have been wasting my time as PostgreSQL is stricter and doesn't allow parameters outside of the `WHERE` clause in the SQL string.  Is this stack overflow answer still the case?

So am I just supposed to concatenate the variables in the SQL string?  This is all internal so is SQL injection still a worry?  Is there a better way to do this?

This post is 8 years old though now so is this still relevant?  I'm going through the PostgreSQL documentation but can't find anything for some reason.  (My google fu isn't up to par apparently)

Thanks all!

Comment: That linked answer is a bit misguided – it's not about parameters being only for where clauses, but that you can't necessarily use parameters for identifiers such as table or column names; OP was trying to do something like `UPDATE foo SET @a=@b`.

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely use parameters wherever you would use a literal value:

```
using System.Data;
using Npgsql;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using var con = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=localhost;Database=postgres");
        con.Open();
        using var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE data AS SELECT generate_series(1, 20) x";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT x, x * @foo + @bar FROM data WHERE x % @divisor = 0";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("foo", 1234.5);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("bar", 72d);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("divisor", 3);
        using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"{reader.GetInt32(0)}: {reader.GetDouble(1)}");
        }
    }
}
```

happily outputs

```
3: 3775.5
6: 7479
9: 11182.5
12: 14886
15: 18589.5
18: 22293
```

so you can see the parameters work both in the `SELECT` list and `WHERE`.

Note that you do not need the `@` sign in the `AddWithValue` call.

Comment: What was that stack overflow post talking about with the `WHERE` clause being the only place for parameters then?  It was from 8 years ago so maybe they changed it?  Or were they wrong to begin with?  I guess I'm back to square one then. :(

Comment: As my comment in your question says, that was a different case – it was when you'd want to use a parameter in place of an identifier such as the `data` table name or the `x` column name.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize that was you up there too.  Gotcha.  Back to square one.  Send good vibes...   :'(

(I'm gonna wait for a few more answers and see if they say anything differently.  You sound like you know what you're talking about though and have 130k rep lol so that's probably the case and I'll likely green checkmark your answer in a bit)

Comment: No need to go back to square one (unless to collect $, if this is Monopoly). I answered your original question too – I think you're just overcomplicating things there by forcibly typing your parameters and casting them around in the query...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `" I think you're just overcomplicating things there by forcibly typing your parameters and casting them around in the query..."?`  What are some code examples of this? It sounds like figuring this out will help me finally fix this.  Thank you.

Comment: @austin-smith-999 Did you have a chance to look at my answer on your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73543988/51685

Comment: I didn't realize that I'll check it out right now!